# How to get a variable from an external function

Tags: python

How, if possible, would I be able to bring in a variable from an external function. Take this code

```
# HttpThing.py
import requests
def httpThing(someurl):
    x = requests.get(someurl)
```

In another file I have

```
from httpThing.py import httpThing
httpThing(www.url.com)
print(x)
```

How would I be able to get the last print function to print the response to the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python- How does return work in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828230/python-how-does-return-work-in-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you return that value from the function like this:

```
# HttpThing.py
import requests
def httpThing(someurl):
    x = requests.get(someurl)
    return x
```

then use it like this:

```
from httpThing import httpThing
x = httpThing(www.url.com)
print(x)
```

**NOTE:** the variable that you return dosen't have to be same as the variable where you call that function for printing it. it could be named anything.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it before but it didn't work but it works now. Huh

Comment: @C.Brownsey did it work now?if so can you accept the answer?

Comment: Sorry. Completely forgot